# Route changes dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm check whether user is logined or not in   `orderscomponent.ts`  by using `jwt token` like below i

```
let userkey = this.storage.get("token");
if (!userkey) {
    this.router.navigate(['signup']);
}
```

And Navigating to `signup` page based on `if-condition`. After redirecting `sign up` page I'm filling the form. On click `sign up`  button code like below in `signupcomponent.ts`

```
<button type="submit" (click)="onSignUp()" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block btn-rounded text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light"></button>
```

in **componet.ts** I have  code like below

```
onSignUp(){
    this.router.navigate([`orderpage`])
}
```

After login the user it is redirecting to same page that is `orderpage` Up to here it is working fine.

Now my question is I'm using same `signupcomponent.ts`
in the home page . When I click on signup it takes me to signup page  and when I click on signup button it should redirect to same home page or profile page . Here I mean is I want to change `this.router.navigate([]) params once already defined`url`to another new`url`

Comment: can you post your code in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: Did you understand my question clearly??

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: What you didn't understand ? please tell so that I will explain more clearly

Comment: You want to navigate to another *url* depending on the parent component?

Comment: @Batajus Yes exactly but the thing is child navigate url should be change dynamically .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two main way that you can use

One it to pass the return url into a service and use by

```
this.router.navigate([[this.urlService.redirectUrl]]);
```

and you just store the url in the service

the other way it to use

```
this.location.back();
```

Which pops the stack and goes back to the previous page [Location Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)

Comment: I didn't get answer. Can you share one live example

Answer (score 1):

As @James Glasgow mentioned you can use service to achieve your goal.

It would look like following sample:

`Service`

```
@Injectable()
export class RouterHelper {
    redirectUrl: string = 'orderpage'; // Defined orderpage as default
}
```

`orderscomponent.ts`

```
this.router.navigate(['signup']).then((successful: boolean) => {
    // Only set the redirectUrl, if the routing is successful
    if (successful) {
        this.routerHelper.redirectUrl = 'orderspage';
    }
});
```

`homepage.component.ts`

```
this.router.navigate(['signup']).then((successful: boolean) => {
    // Only set the redirectUrl, if the routing is successful
    if (successful) { 
        this.routerHelper.redirectUrl = 'homepage'; 
    }
});
```

**Another approach could be to use urls params:**

For this you add params to the navigation function in both components, like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['signup', { parentUrl: 'orderpage'}]);
```

And in your `signupcomponent.ts`:

```
onSignUp() {
    const parentUrl = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('parentUrl');
    this.router.navigate([parentUrl]);
}
```

If you're reuse your `signupcomponent.ts` you should use a subscription to the router params (see [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#snapshot-the-no-observable-alternative)).